# How do I generate a list of possible combinations following a format?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

So, I want to learn how to create a list of all possible combinations using the following format:

AA0AA0A

It needs to be like that, A-Z 0-9 but keeping the position of the characters as showed above.

Comment: Simply use regular expression and you will get the result. And please go through old post there are already solution for the this kind of question.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Does A represent any letter and 0 represent any number?

Comment: @Rocky_Mental I've tried looking, can you link me it? Sorry I'm a beginner :/

Comment: @ReidMoffat thats correct.

Comment: I guess A is character and 0 is the digit here @ReidMoffat

Answer (score 2):

**Using generator**

*Note: updated answer with suggestions from @ShadowRange, @Kelly Bundy, @superb rain)*

```
from string import ascii_uppercase, digits
from itertools import product

def all_combinations():
    ' pattern AA0AA0A '
    A, O = ascii_uppercase, digits
    # Use itertools product to generate all combinations of of 
    # lists of letters and digits
    combs = product(A, A, O, A, A, O, A)
    return map(''.join, combs)
   
# Test
seq = all_combinations() # create generation for combinations

# Show first 20
for i in range(20):
    print(next(seq))
```

**Output**

```
AA0AA0AA
AA0AA0AB
AA0AA0AC
AA0AA0AD
AA0AA0AE
AA0AA0AF
AA0AA0AG
AA0AA0AH
AA0AA0AI
AA0AA0AJ
AA0AA0AK
AA0AA0AL
AA0AA0AM
AA0AA0AN
AA0AA0AO
AA0AA0AP
AA0AA0AQ
AA0AA0AR
AA0AA0AS
AA0AA0AT
```

Comment: @ShadowRanger--right, I was in the middle of correcting this before your message.  Thanks.

Comment: Minor optimization: Replace `for x in combs: yield ''.join(x)` with `yield from map(''.join, combs)`. Pushes more work to C layer outside bytecode interpreter, and as an extra benefit, enables an optimization in `product` that lets it repeatedly reuse the same `tuple` for output because the `tuple` is now always discarded before the next one is requested.

Comment: Now that the end of the product isn't off-scroll anymore, we can see that it's too long :-) (additional A). And returning the map iterator would be faster (see [benchmark](https://preview.tinyurl.com/y5r673kw) with reduced pattern).

Comment: @superbrain--thanks for catching that error.  I adjusted my code accordingly.

Comment: @superbrain: Ah, right, missed there were no other `yield`s, so yeah, just `return map(''.join, combs)`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger--good point that map is already a generator so just `return map(''.join, combs)`.

Answer (score 0):

this is possible, there is 976,562,500 possibilities...

```
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]

combination = []
x = 0
for a in letters:
  for b in letters:
    for c in numbers:
      for d in letters:
        for e in letters:
          for f in numbers:
            for g in letters:
              combination.append(a+b+c+d+e+f+g)
```

Watch out ! This computation may take a while. Also do not attempt to run this script if you don't have more thant 16BG of RAM.

Comment: Where are you getting that number? Seems like it should be higher; `26 ** 5 * 10 ** 2` (~1.2B, ~22% more than your figure). That said, while it probably wouldn't fit in memory, you could *generate* those values one by one, it would just take a while.

Comment: I got this doing this : (26*26*10*26*26*10*26) I tried generating 100,000,000 numbers and  i got stuck at 100% ram use on my 16BG computer

Comment: @Fredericka Does the Canadian alphabet only have 25 letters? :-)

Comment: Seems like learning other languages like python make me forget english... :(

Comment: To get by the memory problem you could turn this into a generator by placing the for loop inside a function and changing the last line to `yield a+b+c+d+e+f+g` rather than `combination.append(a+b+c+d+e+f+g)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JavaScript, there's [Randexp](https://github.com/fent/randexp.js) which generates random strings that match a given regex.

[Releases for browser](https://github.com/fent/randexp.js/releases)